# What improvements can be made to this?

Tags: java, recursion

I've written a function which can get the environment variables value. The input parameter would be as follows

${machine}/bin or ${machine/bin} or ${machine}/bin${path${OS}}/path 
I would need to check the values which start with ${} 
I've written a function which is kinda recursive in nature, but would appreciate it if anyone can review the code for me and tell me what can be done better

```
private String replaceWithEnvironmentVariables(String specialChars) {
    String result="";
    boolean flag=true;
    try{
        result = specialChars;
        String temp = "";
        char loopBreaker = '}';
        char dollarCheck = '$';
        char slashCheck = '/';
        int index = result.indexOf("{");
        if (index == -1){
            result = result.replaceAll("[{},$]", "");
            return result;
        }
        for (int i = index; i < result.length(); i++) {
            if(slashCheck==result.charAt(i))
                break;
            temp += result.charAt(i);
            if(dollarCheck==result.charAt(i) || loopBreaker==result.charAt(i)){
                break;
            }
        }
        String sub = temp.replaceAll("[{},$/]", "");
        if(sub==null || sub.length()==0){
            sub="";
            flag=false;
            result = result.replace(temp, sub);
        }
        if(flag){
            String returnSub = getEnvironmentVariableValue(sub);
            result = result.replace(temp, returnSub);
        }
    }catch(NullPointerException nullPointer){
        nullPointer.printStackTrace();
    }catch(Exception except){
        except.printStackTrace();
    }
    return replaceWithEnvironmentVariables(result);
}
```

PS: The code is working, but I'm just here to know what I do to improve this. If this question seems to be off-topic I'm terribly sorry.

Comment: This question appears to be better suited for [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), once additional explanations are added on what OP wants to review/improve specifically.

Comment: @Mena already posted and got some awesome reviews... :)